# WebView properties not changing after scrolling

Tags: android, webview, horizontal-scrolling

What I'm trying to do is change the font size and foreground/background color of a webview.
I have done this using the following method (placed inside the activity):

```
private void updateFont(int fontSize, String fontColor) {
  if (fontSize != 0) {
    contentWebview.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);
  }
  if (!fontColor.equals("")) {
    contentWebview.loadUrl(fontColor);
  }
}
```

Now this is working fine. However I added something to my contentWebview (which is a custom webview I created) - below is some snippet of the custom webview:

```
public class ContentWebview extends WebView {

  public ContentWebview(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public ContentWebview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    loadWebview();

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new OnTouchListener() {
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
    };
    setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
  }

  class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
      try {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {                 
          return false;
        }
        // right to left swipe
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
          int currentPosition = getScrollX()/displayWidth +1;
            scrollTo(currentPosition*displayWidth, 0);
        }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
          int currentPosition = getScrollX()/displayWidth;
            scrollTo(currentPosition*displayWidth, 0);
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // nothing
      }
      return true;
    }
  }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      int currentPosition = getScrollX()/displayWidth;
      if(getScrollX()%displayWidth>displayWidth/2) {
        currentPosition++;
      } else {
        // do nothing
      }     
      scrollTo(currentPosition*displayWidth, 0);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
  }
```

Basically I've created a custom WebView that snaps to a fixed calculated position when it is scrolled or flinged. Now this is where the problem arises - once I scrolled this particular webview, the previous method (updateFont) doesn't work anymore - the webview doesn't change font size or color.

I have also narrowed down the problem to this particular line:

```
setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

If I comment out this line, the `updateFont` method works again even after I scrolled the webview, but the snap-to-page on fling functionality of my webview is also gone.

What am I missing here?

Update: Problem only occurs in froyo devices. 2.3 and above doesn't seem to have the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tinkering with the project, I found out that the property changes loaded in the custom webview is interpreted after some time. The delay is caused by an onNewPictureListener triggering an endless call to a javascript command, which gets interpreted by the webview first, before executing other stuff. Removing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with the WebView and GestureDetectors - try *always* returning **false** in your `onFling(..)` method instead of **true** - using a gesture detector in the fashion you do is known to block pretty basic stuff (such as even updating the currently displayed page).